# What does the '#*:*' mean in an Elasticsearch query explanation?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Every time I hit the `_validate/query?explain` endpoint with one of my `multi_match` queries I get the usual Lucene query syntax plus something I don't recognize. For example:

```
{
   'query': {
        'multi_match': { 
            'query': 'basketball with cartoon aliens',
            'fields': ['title^10', 'overview']
        }
    }
}
```

Becomes

```
'+((title:basketball title:with 'title:cartoon title:aliens)^10.0
  |(overview:basketball overview:with overview:cartoon overview:aliens)) #*:*'
```

This `#*:*`, what does it mean?

Comment: what's ELK version you're using?

Comment: Elasticsearch 6.4.0